# To create a 6 * 6 color palette using html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-canvas

I want to create a clickable 6 * 6 color palette using HTML5 Canvas. I should be able to click on each color grid on the palette and the background color should change to the selected color.

Comment: You don't need canvas to do this - and in fact using canvas means you'll need to implement your own cursor click tracking logic. Why do you want to use canvas?

Comment: Going along with @Dai 's comment: Just use simple HTML tables and have JavaScript generate all of them in a `for` loop. In each iteration have it create the html element and add a certain amount to an `rgb` color for each iteration.

Comment: Not a clear question ... Well, you can set the canvas fill color with `context.fillStyle='red'` and then draw one of your 6x6 rectangles with `context.fillRect( column*columnSize, row*rowSize, columnSize, rowSize)` You can listen for click events on the canvas using `myCanvasElement.onclick = function(event) { ... };`. You can change the background color of an element with `anyElement.style.backgroundColor='red'`

Comment: @Dai.. My task is to use HTML5 Canvas. I could solve it using Tables. 
Reframing my ques:
I want to create a 6 * 6 color palette(grids), each grid with a different color.
On selecting a paricular color grid, my background should change to that particular color.

Answer (score 0):

Using React, I made this. Maybe after looking this over you'll have an idea of what all you'll need to do.

```js
class Palette extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { color: '#FFFFFF' };
  }
  
  setColor(row, col) {
    const color = this.getColor(row, col);

    this.setState({ color });
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }
  
  getColor(row, col) {
    const hue = Math.floor(col / this.props.height * 360);
    const sat = 100;
    const lit = Math.floor((1 - (row + 1) / (this.props.width + 1)) * 100);
    
    return `hsl(${hue},${sat}%,${lit}%)`;
  }
  
  render() {
    const rows = [];
    
    for (let i = 0; i < this.props.height; i++) {
      const cols = [];
      
      for (let j = 0; j < this.props.width; j++) {
        
        cols.push(
          <div
            className="col"
            onClick={
              () => this.setColor(j, i)
            }
            style={{
              backgroundColor: this.getColor(j, i)
            }} />
        );
      }
  
      rows.push(
        <div className="row">
          {cols}
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    return (
      <div className="palette">
        {rows}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Palette width={6} height={6} />, document.body);
```

```css
.palette {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.col {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: To add to this, you can use `cxt.getImageData()` to get the color of the square you click on. Then all you have to do is set the background according to that color. (This is just a basic ToDo list. The rest you'll have to figure out. Try googling!)

Comment: Thanks. that helps. I would like to know if this is possible using Bootstrap also.

Comment: @NandanaSrinivasan there's no point in using Bootstrap if you're going to use a canvas

Comment: Ok. I am entirely new to JS and its frameworks. Thank you.